# How get positions of array without repeating positions?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

i have problems with an array, i want get the values of positions, but without repeating the positions(with the next.random the values are repeat, but i need once get the position), i post my code for you see them. i hope you can help me.

```
  int d = 0;   

  for (int i = 0; i < caminohormiga.Length; i++)
       {
          int start2 = random.Next(0, caminohormiga.Length);

          d = caminohormiga[start2];
          MatrizAux[i] = d;

          if (caminohormiga[i] == 0)
             {
              Console.Write("Repetido");
             }
         Console.Write(caminohormiga[i] + ", ");
       }
```

Comment: `the values of positions, but without repeating the positions`? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: If you are using random to get a position it's more than likely you'll get repeats. Can you include more of the code?

Comment: All good dude... I seem to be very busy now... Good thing I guess! You at SO yet?

Comment: (with the next.random the values are repeat, but i need once get the position) thnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an array of indexes, fill it with numbers zero through length minus one, make a random shuffle, and go through the shuffled array to pick the index of the original array.

You can use [*Fisher-Yates Shuffle algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to re-arrange the indexes.

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, caminohormiga.Length).ToArray();
// Run Fisher-Yates algorithm on indexes
...
foreach (var i in indexes) {
    var randomNoRepeat = caminohormiga[i];
    ...
}
```